# Need assistance concerning a scanner error java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am working on a project to calculate fractions, however this program is just meant to read user input and return part of it but instead results in the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at fracCalc.fracCalcCheckUno.produceAnswer(fracCalcCheckUno.java:21)
    at fracCalc.fracCalcCheckUno.main(fracCalcCheckUno.java:14)
```

#### Expected Behavior

The code should read the user input and then return the second part of it, which I have called "operand2"

#### Current Behavior

Code results in the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at fracCalc.fracCalcCheckUno.produceAnswer(fracCalcCheckUno.java:21)
    at fracCalc.fracCalcCheckUno.main(fracCalcCheckUno.java:14)
```

#### Context

With this error I am unable to receive any user input.

#### Steps to Reproduce (for bugs)

```
package fracCalc;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class fracCalcCheckUno{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input fraction expression: ");
        String phrase = a.next();
        String b = produceAnswer(phrase);
        System.out.println(b);
    }    
    public static String produceAnswer(String phrase) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(phrase);
        String operand1 = console.next();
        String operator = console.next();
        String operand2 = console.next();
        String answer = produceAnswer(phrase);
        System.out.println(answer);

        return operand2;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a recursive call, why are you doing recursive call `String answer = produceAnswer(phrase);`

Answer (score 0):

`String phrase = a.next();` only takes a single token from your scanner variable `a` before passing the token into your method. What you are currently doing is trying to get 3 tokens from your scanner, but the scanner is only given 1 token at initialization, which causes your exception. You need to change to `String phrase = a.nextLine();` in order to get the entire line of tokens.

You also need to change `String answer = produceAnswer(phrase);` to something else because you are currently calling `produceAnswer(phrase)` in an infinite recursive loop, which results in StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the base case.
There is nothing to get from `scanner` at some point in the flow.
that is why it is giving

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
```